# go get fyne/io/driver/gl@v1.0.1 unrecognized import path

Tags: go, installation, fyne

Trying to follow the installation guide [here](http://github.com/HFO4/gameboy.live) and most of the process is working. I'm having an issue with building it however.
When trying to build I'm getting this message:

> C:...\gameboy.live>go build -o gbdotlive main.go
> ......\go\pkg\mod\fyne.io\fyne@v1.0.1\driver\gl\gl.go:20:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package github.com/goki/freetype (imported by fyne.io/fyne/driver/gl); to add:
> go get fyne.io/fyne/driver/gl@v1.0.1

Running the suggested command however raises another prompt:

> C:...\gameboy.live>go get fyne.io/driver/gl@v1.0.1
> go get fyne.io/driver/gl@v1.0.1: unrecognized import path "fyne.io/driver/gl": reading https://fyne.io/driver/gl?go-get=1: 404 Not Found

I've tried going for the version 1.4.3 driver too which raises a different error:

> C:...\gameboy.live>go get fyne.io/fyne/gl@v1.4.3
> go get: module fyne.io/fyne@v1.4.3 found, but does not contain package fyne.io/fyne/gl

Anybody familiar with this issue? FYI I'm on Windows and have MinGw installed already.

Comment: It looks like you have not copied the suggested commands correctly which is leading to the further errors. However it looks like the repo may be out of date

Comment: There is a newer version of the Fyne GUI aspects of the gameboy repo at https://github.com/andydotxyz/fynegameboy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run `go mod tidy` before exec `go build -o gbdotlive main.go`.Have a try.